# Python output to be read inside bash script line by line

Tags: python, bash, loops, lines

Basic idea here is to call 1 file from the asd directory and 1 line from the output.txt file in each curl call:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
python MJD.py -> output.txt
FILES=/home/user/asd/*
for f in $FILES
do
filename="$output.txt"
while read -r line
do
curl -F ID='zero' -F dir="@$f" -F TIME="$line" -F outputFormat=json "http://blabla"
done
done
```

This code actually calls the python script and saves the output inside the output.txt file. The output file is just 1 number on each line for several lines. Now what I want to do is to get, starting from the first line, for -F TIME=" one value inside the text file".

I don't know what part of my code is causing the problem. When I call this script the part calling the files from dir works but for every time the TIME=0 appears on screen, looks like nothing is read from the output.txt file.. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good place for a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) and `exec`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

exec 4< <( python MJD.py - )
# now, the output from the python script can be read from channel 4

for file in /home/user/asd/*; do
    IFS= read -u4 -r time              # get the next line from MJD.py
    curl -F ID='zero' -F dir="@$file" -F TIME="$time" -F outputFormat=json "http://blabla"
done
```

That exec "trick" is specified [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-exec):

> > `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`
>
> [...] If no *command* is specified, redirections may be used to affect the current shell environment.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything works like a charm. I understood the idea but I should look into that manual and learn more about this. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're not feeding your inner loop the output file, try:

```
#!/bin/bash
python MJD.py > output.txt
FILES=/home/user/asd/*
for f in $FILES
do
filename="output.txt"
while read -r line
do
curl -F ID='zero' -F dir="@$f" -F TIME="$line" -F outputFormat=json "http://blabla"
done < "$filename"
done
```

Although, since you're already using Python, why not just write all the logic in Python and deal with everything at one place?

Comment: I have understood the situation here and corrected it now it works. However, it goes for all values to all values. There are 2 files in the dir path and there are 2 values in the txt file. When this code works it applies everyone 1 by 1 creates 4 results.. What I need is only 2 results 1 entry from dir and 1 line from the txt starting from first and goes until they finish for the first time so only 2 results and once it done the loop to stop.